# when I use indy-sdk, "pool.open_pool_ledger" report a network timeout error

Tags: hyperledger-indy

when I using "pool.open_pool_ledger", it report a network timeout error.

But accessing with other roles, such as using the wallet.open_wallet function, will not encounter network errors.

The log is as:

```
2023-07-24 16:44:57,015 DEBUG _get_error_details: >>>
2023-07-24 16:44:57,015 DEBUG _get_error_details: <<< error_details: {'backtrace': '', 'message': 'Error: Pool timeout\n Caused by: Pool timeout\n'}
2023-07-24 16:44:57,015 DEBUG _indy_callback: >>> command_handle: 2, err , args: (0,)
2023-07-24 16:44:57,016 DEBUG _indy_callback: <<<
2023-07-24 16:44:57,016 DEBUG _indy_loop_callback: >>> command_handle: 2, err , args: (0,)
2023-07-24 16:44:57,016 WARNING _indy_loop_callback: Function returned error 
2023-07-24 16:44:57,016 DEBUG _indy_loop_callback <<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Wallet functions do not need to connect to the ledger, so you can run them without connecting to any pool.

The problem you are having might be due to a malformed `genesis.txn` file, but it is impossible to know without more details.

If you are using docker you can find the genesis file by running

```
docker exec -it YourDockerContainerName /bin/bash

cd var/lib/indy/NetworkName
```

the `genesis.txn` file should be in this folder.

Also, `usr/local/bin` has a lot of scripts you can use to check the ledger state, transactions etc. (ex: ./read_ledger --type domain for domain transactions)